# Error Using Multiple Database In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm trying to implement mutiple database in CI. My code Is here:

```
//database.php
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "root";
$db['default']['database'] = "ravelex";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "rvx_";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$db['smf']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['smf']['username'] = "root";
$db['smf']['password'] = "root";
$db['smf']['database'] = "smf";
$db['smf']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['smf']['dbprefix'] = "smf_";
$db['smf']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['smf']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['smf']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['smf']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['smf']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['smf']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

The model is

```
//user_model.php
class user_model extends Model {
    private $ravelex_db;
    function user_model() {
        parent::Model();
        $this->ravelex_db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
    }

    function find_all() {
        print_r($this->ravelex_db);
        $q = $this->ravelex_db->get('users');
        return $q->result();
    }
}

//smf_user_model.php
class smf_user_model extends Model {
    private $smf_db;

    function smf_user_model() {
        parent::Model();
        $this->smf_db = $this->load->database('smf', TRUE);
    }

    function find_all() {
        $q = $this->smf_db->get('members');
        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

Controller tester

```
    class mutipledb extends Controller {

    function mutipledb() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('smf_user_model');
    }

    function index() {
        print_r($this->user_model->find_all());
        print_r($this->smf_user_model->find_all());
    }
}
```

There are some error, The first database uses the second database name. But it still use it's prefix.

The error is

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146
Table 'smf.rvx_users' doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM (`rvx_users`)
```

If I just load one model ..., It works.
class mutipledb extends Controller {

```
    function mutipledb() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->database();
        //$this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('smf_user_model');
    }

    function index() {
        //print_r($this->user_model->find_all());
        print_r($this->smf_user_model->find_all());
    }
}
```

Why this could be happened ? Help me please

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124993/mutiple-database-in-codeigniter. Please do not duplicate your questions, you can instead edit your existing question to provide more details.

Comment: I found this post more helpful than the other post.  Thanks Adi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Set pconnect to FALSE for both database configuration or one of database configuration.

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['smf']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

OR

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['smf']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
//and vice versa
```